# Drawback of product collection written in phtml

Tags: magento-1.9, collection, product-collection

I have doubt with product collection

```
<?php 

    $categoryIds = array(469);//category id
    $products = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
    ->addCategoryFilter(Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryIds));
    $Collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $products->getAllIds()));;
    $Collection->addAttributeToSelect(array(
                                       'image','small_image',
                                       'name',
                                       'short_description'
                       ))
    ->addFieldToFilter('visibility', array(
                                   Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH,
                                   Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_IN_CATALOG
                       )) 
    ->setOrder('price', 'ASC')

    ->joinField('qty',
                 'cataloginventory/stock_item',
                 'qty',
                 'product_id=entity_id',
                 '{{table}}.stock_id=1',
                 'left')
     ->addAttributeToFilter('qty', array("gt" => 0))

    ->addFinalPrice()
    ->getSelect()
    ->where('price_index.final_price < price_index.price')
    ?>
```

I wrote in this collection to my phtml it's working fine. But what is the drawback to written collection in phtml

I feel after that site little bit slow. Then I wrote MVC But i don't know how to call in that phtml.

Comment: where you add this function?? mean model or block?

Comment: @QaisarSatti i don't where add and how to call can you please explain me

Comment: Also i want to know what is the draw back if i written in phtml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The phtml file is a view, so you should not work directly on database there. Instead try to create a model, use that in the block and then call the prepared data from the block object.**

Comment: Ok thanks What's drawback if i will write in phtml

Comment: There is none. it will work but you must follow the mvc structure.

Comment: Okay But i feel site is slow after written this under phtml

Comment: query take same time to execute. check the query how much time it take `echo $products->getSelect();`

Comment: How to check how much time it will take it dispaly SELECT `e`.*, `cat_index`.`position` AS `cat_index_position` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index` AS `cat_index` ON cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id=1 AND cat_index.category_id = '469'

Comment: execute this query in database and check the execution time..

Comment: it shows Query took 0.0031 sec

Comment: then it is not taking much time. Just add query function  in model and call that model method in block and then block method to phtml

Comment: Ok i will check it